# How to script sharing in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to run a script from a spreadsheet that shares the spreadsheet with a user defined in the script. The script will run whenever a button in the sheet is clicked (I have that part down). It's basically a custom share button, the advantage being that it saves the user a few clicks and they don't have to worry about who to share with and what permissions to give them.

Very simple, but I can't find a share function in the documentation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See driveApp. Its all there.
Its not in spreadsheetApp